# Why won't videos on a particular website play under Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: video, flash, codecs

Very oddly, I cannot watch any videos a TV channel website, for example this one: http://www.kanald.com.tr/GalipDervis/Videolar/

I can see from the frame source that it contains an embedded Adobe Flash video and some Java scripts (all of which don't pose any problems elsewhere).

I've tried different web browsers (Chrome/Chromium/Firefox), but it seems I have some sort of video codec problem in my system.

I have installed all sorts of gstreamer plugins, codecs, etc. (maybe too many?) to avoid such problems, but strangely I can watch these videos using Linux Mint 15 Live Session on the same machine.

**I wonder how I can find out why a particular video (like this one) won't work on my system?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might have to do with a layer of abstraction on top of Flash. You can try to install the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL):

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Reboot your browser afterwards. This will *not* work on Chrome, though.

Sources:

- http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/m6replay
- http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html

Comment: Voila!!! I installed **hal**, and also performed everything suggested on http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/m6replay ( and also had to disable some adblocking ;-) and then I could see **Firefox** pass the test on http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/flash-player-11-problems-playing.html and eventually play the videos on www.kanald.com.tr

Comment: Ah that's nice Sadi. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Chrome, you will have to uninstall Flash.  Chrome has flash built-in.

Chrome uses the latest version of flash while Adobe stopped providing updates to Flash for Linux.

I use Chrome and the video runs fine.  I uninstalled Flash.

Actually, I cannot see that flash video.  I guess the problem is not Flash related.

Comment: I also prefer Chrome (currently using version 31.xxx) but unfortunately uninstalling Adobe Flash plugin didn't result in having the videos concerned played. I wonder if you can see the video play at http://www.kanald.com.tr/GalipDervis/Videolar/